# Removing get_permalink in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on my website and I'd like to remove the page links in a widget, so the title and content shows but the page isn't accessible.
Can anyone help please? Thank you.

```
<?php
   echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" class="all-link">';
   the_title();
   echo '</a>';
    ?>
```

Comment: You might want to add some commentary to the code fragment to explain why it is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just erase the `a` tag and all its attributes, plus you won't need an `echo` for `the_title(); or`the_content()` , since those WP functions already echo those:

```
<?php
   the_title();
?>
```